# How to remove focus on a on focus menu on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hamburger menu, when I click the button it activates the on target class on shows the menu. While the menu to open I am not sure how to make it if I click on the menu icon again it collapses the menu. Here is the code I got so far.

```js
// my attempt in js to blur navTarget:focus
$("nav a").click(function() {
  $("nav a").removeClass("navselected");
  $(this).addClass("navselected");
});

$("#menu").click(function() {
  $("#navTarget:focus").blur();
});
```

```css
nav {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid #386BA8;
  background-color: #386BA8;
}

nav header {
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #386BA8;
}

nav a:first-child {
  padding: 0;
  border-top: none;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #6699CC;
  top: 0rem;
  display: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.bufferspace {
  padding: 0;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #6699CC;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

#menu i {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#navTarget {
  padding-top: 2.8rem;
}

#navTarget:target {
  display: block;
}

nav a:first-child:hover {
  animation: none;
}

nav a:first-child:hover {
  animation: none;
}

.navselected:first-child {
  background-color: none;
  border-left: none;
}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav id="navbar">
  <a id="menu" href="#navTarget">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <div id="navTarget" class="navigation">
    <header id="main-title">
      <a href="#navbar">
        <h1>HTML<br class="hide" /> Documentation</h1>
      </a>
    </header>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#Introduction">Introduction</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#Syntax">Syntax</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#HTML_Page">HTML Page</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#Common_Tags">Common Tags</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#HTML5">HTML5</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Here is the link to my Codepen](https://codepen.io/peterwebdev/pen/ZRqydm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the href from the menu button and `:target` style from CSS, instead add this style on class change.

```
$("#menu").on("click", function() {
  $("#navTarget").toggleClass("openMenu");
});
```

```js
$("#menu").on("click", function() {
  $("#navTarget").toggleClass("openMenu");
});
$(".nav-link").on("click", function() {
  $("#navTarget").removeClass("openMenu");
});
```

```css
nav {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid #386BA8;
  background-color: #386BA8;
}

nav header {
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #386BA8;
}

nav a:first-child {
  padding: 0;
  border-top: none;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #6699CC;
  top: 0rem;
  display: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.bufferspace {
  padding: 0;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #6699CC;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

#menu i {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#navTarget {
  padding-top: 2.8rem;
}

#navTarget.openMenu {
  display: block;
}

nav a:first-child:hover {
  animation: none;
}

nav a:first-child:hover {
  animation: none;
}

.navselected:first-child {
  background-color: none;
  border-left: none;
}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css'>
<nav id="navbar">
  <a id="menu">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <div id="navTarget" class="navigation">

    <header id="main-title">
      <a href="#navbar">
        <h1>HTML<br class="hide" /> Documentation</h1>
      </a>
    </header>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#Introduction">Introduction</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#Syntax">Syntax</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#HTML_Page">HTML Page</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#Common_Tags">Common Tags</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#HTML5">HTML5</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe below solution fixes your problem. I use `$("#navTarget").toggleClass("visible");` to toggle CSS class which makes `navTarget` visible.

```js
$("nav a").click(function() {
  $("#navTarget").toggleClass("visible");
});

$("#menu").click(function() {
  $("#navTarget:focus").blur();
});
```

```css
nav {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid #386BA8;
  background-color: #386BA8;
}

nav header {
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #386BA8;
}

nav a:first-child {
  padding: 0;
  border-top: none;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #6699CC;
  top: 0rem;
  display: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.bufferspace {
  padding: 0;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #6699CC;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

#menu i {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#navTarget {
  padding-top: 2.8rem;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}

nav a:first-child:hover {
  animation: none;
}

nav a:first-child:hover {
  animation: none;
}

.navselected:first-child {
  background-color: none;
  border-left: none;
}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css'>
<nav id="navbar">
  <a id="menu" href="#navTarget">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <div id="navTarget" class="navigation">
    <header id="main-title">
      <a href="#navbar">
        <h1>HTML<br class="hide" /> Documentation</h1>
      </a>
    </header>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#Introduction">Introduction</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#Syntax">Syntax</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#HTML_Page">HTML Page</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#Common_Tags">Common Tags</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#HTML5">HTML5</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey try the following code and check the output it will fullfill your requirement. I used toggle() jquery function which toggles the navigation to display:block and display:none;

```js
$("nav a").click(function() {
    $("nav a").removeClass("navselected");
    $(this).addClass("navselected");
});

$("#menu").click(function() {
      // $("#navTarget:focus").blur();
  $(".navigation").toggle();
});
```

```css
nav{
 flex:0 0 100%;
 border-right:1px solid #386BA8; 
 background-color:#386BA8; 
 }
 nav header{
  padding:0rem 1rem;
 }
nav a{
 display: block;
 color:#000; 
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:1rem;
 border-top:1px solid #386BA8;

}
nav a:first-child{
 padding:0;
 border-top:none;

}

 .navigation{
  background-color:#6699CC;
  top:0rem;

    display: none;
 }


 .hide{display: none;}
 .bufferspace{padding: 0;}

 #menu{
  background-color:#6699CC;
  
  display: block;
  position:fixed;
  
  cursor:pointer;
  top:0;
  z-index: 10;



 }
 #menu i{
  font-size:2rem;
  padding:1rem;
 }

 #navTarget{
  padding-top:2.8rem;
 }

 nav a:first-child:hover {
  animation:none;
 }
 nav a:first-child:hover {
  animation:none;
 }
 .navselected:first-child{
 background-color:none; 
  border-left:none;
}
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css'>
<nav id="navbar">
        <a id="menu" href="#navTarget">
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
        <div id="navTarget" class="navigation">

          <header id="main-title"><a href="#navbar"><h1>HTML<br class="hide"/> Documentation</h1></a></header>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#Introduction">Introduction</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#Syntax">Syntax</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#HTML_Page">HTML Page</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#Common_Tags">Common Tags</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#HTML5">HTML5</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```